# BASH script : Integrated document creation hangs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redirect

I find that a piece of my bash script causes the hang up. I extract it here :

```
#!/bin/bash
cat << EndOfFspreadFile >> ./myscript.sh 
echo Enter Source Path : 
read SRCPATH
FILECNT=`find $SRCPATH/* 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
FILECNTERR=`find $SRCPATH/* 2>&1 | grep "find:" | wc -l`
echo count : $FILECNT
echo problems : $FILECNTERR
EndOfFspreadFile
echo done
```

This script is expected to just append the script part in the integrated block into myscript.sh file. But it just HANGS !
    Thanks !
- Mohamed -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $ variables and back quotes will get expanded. You need to escape them in script.
Right now you end up searching the entire filesystem.

Basically, `find $SRCPATH/* 2>/dev/null | wc -l` gets executed as `find /* 2>/dev/null | wc -l`

Here is how you can rewrite it (just one line example):

```
FILECNT=\$(find \$SRCPATH/* 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
```

By the way, it's easy to find out if you run `bash -x <your script>`.

Comment: An easier way to prevent expansion would be to wrap the sentinel in single quotes: `cat <<'EndOfFspreadFile' >> ./myscript.sh`

Comment: Thanks Alex !
Thanks Josh ! 
It helped me a lot !